# Skip creating resources when environment is different

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm wanting to deploy a CodeBuild/CodePipeline to run JMeter Tests. I only want this to deploy in my development environment `"dev"`. I've got it working so it deploys to Dev but if I try another environment `"test"` I want it to skip these resources. When I run it I get the following `Error: Missing resource instance key`. This seems like it's going to try and plan/apply these resources.

I've got a `count = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0` against every resource  but it will try and deploy the resources into Test environment:

Here is my Terraform config: If someone can review to see what I could do else to get this working.

I just want it only to deploy when `local.environment = "dev"`

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "codebuild_load_test_bucket" {
  count = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  # checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_144: "Ensure that S3 bucket has cross-region replication enabled"
  # checkov:skip=CKV2_AWS_62: "Ensure S3 buckets should have event notifications enabled"
  bucket = local.codebuild_load_test_bucket_name
  tags = {
    "Name" = local.codebuild_load_test_bucket_name
  }
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "codebuild_load_test_bucket" {
  count = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  bucket = local.environment == "dev" ? aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].id : null
  acl    = "private"
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls.s3_bucket_acl_ownership]
}

# Resource to avoid error "AccessControlListNotSupported: The bucket does not allow ACLs"
resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "s3_bucket_acl_ownership" {
  # checkov:skip=CKV2_AWS_65: "Ensure access control lists for S3 buckets are disabled"
  count = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  bucket = local.environment == "dev" ? aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].id : null
  rule {
    object_ownership = "ObjectWriter"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "codebuild_load_test_bucket" {
  count = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  bucket = local.environment == "dev" ? aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].id : null
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "codebuild_load_test_bucket" {
  count = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  bucket = local.environment == "dev" ? aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].id : null
  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      kms_master_key_id = local.environment == "dev" ? aws_kms_key.s3_codebuild_buckets_load_test[0].key_id : null
      sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_logging" "codebuild_load_test_bucket" {
  count = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  bucket        = local.environment == "dev" ? aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].id : null
  depends_on    = [aws_s3_bucket_acl.access_logs_bucket]
  target_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.access_logs_bucket.bucket
  target_prefix = "${local.codebuild_load_test_bucket_name}/"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "codebuild_load_test_bucket" {
  count = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  bucket     = local.environment == "dev" ? aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].id : null
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_versioning.codebuild_load_test_bucket]
  rule {
    id     = "${local.environment}-${local.codebuild_load_test_bucket_name}-source-lifecycle"
    status = "Enabled"
    filter {
      prefix = "source/"
    }
    expiration {
      days = 90
    }
    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      noncurrent_days = 1
    }
  }
  rule {
    id     = "${local.environment}-${local.codebuild_load_test_bucket_name}-codeSource-lifecycle"
    status = "Enabled"
    filter {
      prefix = "${local.codepipeline_proj_load_test_name}/codeSource/"
    }
    expiration {
      days = 14
    }
    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      noncurrent_days = 1
    }
  }
  rule {
    id     = "abort-failed-multipart-uploads"
    status = "Enabled"
    filter {}
    abort_incomplete_multipart_upload {
      days_after_initiation = 7
    }
  }
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "codebuild_load_test_bucket" {
  count = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  bucket = local.environment == "dev" ? aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].id : null

  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
  restrict_public_buckets = true
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "codebuild_load_test_bucket_policy" {
  count = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  statement {
    sid    = "AllowCodebuildToPublishArtifactsToS3Bucket"
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["codebuild.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:ListBucket",
      "s3:Get*",
    ]
    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].arn}/*"
    ]
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      values   = local.build_source_arn_allowed
    }
  }
  statement {
    sid    = "AllowCodepipelineToPublishArtifactsToS3Bucket"
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["codepipeline.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:ListBucket",
      "s3:Get*",
    ]
    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].arn}/*"
    ]
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      values   = local.pipeline_source_arn_allowed
    }
  }
  statement {
    sid    = "AllowLambdaToS3Bucket"
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:ListBucket",
      "s3:Get*",
    ]
    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].arn}/*"
    ]
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      values   = [local.source_code_copier_arn]
    }
  }
  statement {
    sid    = "AllowLambdaRoleToS3Bucket"
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [local.source_code_copier_role_arn]
    }
    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:ListBucket",
      "s3:Get*",
    ]
    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].arn}/*"
    ]
  }
  statement {
    sid    = "BlockNonHTTPSTraffic"
    effect = "Deny"
    principals {
      type        = "*"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }
    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].arn}/*"
    ]
    actions = ["s3:*"]
    condition {
      test     = "Bool"
      variable = "aws:SecureTransport"
      values   = ["false"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "codebuild_load_test_bucket_policy" {
  count = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  bucket = local.environment == "dev" ? aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].id : null
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.codebuild_load_test_bucket_policy[0].json

}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "codebuild_load_test_cloudwatch_log_group" {
  count = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  # checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_338: "CloudWatch log groups retains logs for a custom period so this finding can be ignored"
  name              = local.codebuild_load_test_log_group_name
  kms_key_id        = aws_kms_key.cloudwatch_log_key.arn
  retention_in_days = local.cloudwatch_log_retention_days
}


resource "aws_codebuild_project" "codebuild_jmeter_tests" {
  # checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_147: "Ensure that CodeBuild projects are encrypted"
  # being ignored as projects are encrypted by default and encryption should be deployed on project creation
  count = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0

  name         = local.codebuild_proj_load_test_name
  description  = "Runs JMeter tests for the application"
  service_role = data.aws_iam_role.pipeline_role[0].arn


  environment {
    compute_type = local.codebuild_load_test_compute_type
    image        = local.codebuild_load_test_image
    type         = local.codebuild_load_test_container_type
  }

  artifacts {

    location  = local.environment == "dev" ? aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].id : null
    name      = local.codebuild_load_test_artifact_name
    type      = "S3"
    path      = local.codebuild_load_test_artifact_path
    packaging = "ZIP"
  }

  source {
    type            = "GITHUB"
    location        = local.github_repo_url
    git_clone_depth = 1
    buildspec       = "./build_spec_load_test.yaml"
    # Add authentication details if needed (e.g., OAuth token)
  }
  logs_config {
    cloudwatch_logs {
      group_name  = local.environment == "dev" ? aws_cloudwatch_log_group.codebuild_load_test_cloudwatch_log_group[0].name : null
      stream_name = local.codebuild_load_test_cloudwatch_stream_name
    }
  }
  tags = {
    "Name" = local.codebuild_proj_load_test_name
  }
}


# KMS Key for S3 Codebuild Load Test buckets UNIQUE DO NOT REUSE ELSEWHERE
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_codebuild_buckets_load_test" {
  count = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  # Skips are placed as the policies below restrict the use of the key to certain services and actions.
  # checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_109: "Ensure IAM policies does not allow permissions management / resource exposure without constraints"
  # checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_356: "Ensure no IAM policies documents allow "*" as a statement's resource for restrictable actions"
  # checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_111: "Ensure IAM policies does not allow write access without constraints"
  statement {
    sid    = "Enable Pipeline Role Management of the Key"
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      # Limiting key management to the pipeline role alone.
      type = "AWS"
      # Had to include interpolation for a localstack workaround
      identifiers = local.environment == "dev" ? ["arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:root"] : [data.aws_iam_role.pipeline_role[0].arn]
    }
    actions   = ["kms:*"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
  # Enabled IAM Role permissions from resources wanting to use the key
  statement {
    sid    = "IAM Role KMS Access"
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:root"]
    }
    actions = [
      "kms:Decrypt*",
      "kms:Describe*",
      "kms:Encrypt*",
      "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
      "kms:ReEncrypt*"
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
  }

  # Cross region Key access requires KMS Key policy statement and counterpart in higher account.
  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = local.environment == "dev" ? [] : ["arn:aws:iam::${local.destination_account_id[local.environment]}:role/${local.dest_env_name[local.environment]}--source-code-copier-execute-role"]
    content {
      sid    = "HigherAccountKMSAccess"
      effect = "Allow"
      principals {
        type = "AWS"
        identifiers = [
          statement.value
        ]
      }
      actions = [
        "kms:Encrypt*",
        "kms:Decrypt*",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*"
      ]
      resources = ["*"]
      condition {
        test     = "StringLike"
        variable = "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:s3:arn"
        values   = ["${aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket.arn}/*"]
      }
    }
  }
}
resource "aws_kms_key" "s3_codebuild_buckets_load_test" {
  count                   = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  description             = "KMS Key for S3 Codebuild Load Test bucket"
  deletion_window_in_days = local.kms_key_deletion_duration
  enable_key_rotation     = true

  policy = local.environment == "dev" ? data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_codebuild_buckets_load_test[0].json : null

  tags = {
    Name = "${local.environment}--s3-codebuild"
  }
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "s3_codebuild_buckets_load_test" {
  count         = aws_kms_key.s3_codebuild_buckets_load_test[*].id != null && local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  name          = "alias/${local.environment}-s3-codebuild_load_test"
  target_key_id = local.environment == "dev" ? aws_kms_key.s3_codebuild_buckets_load_test[0].arn : null
}
```

Comment: Does it give you a specific line that is causing the error?

Comment: You just need to put the ternary operator in count. Then you don't need to repeat it on every other resource field. That's likely what is causing your issue

Comment: To be more specific, you need only `count = local.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0` then you can proceed the other fields, like bucket, without repeating the condition, but just `bucket = aws_s3_bucket.codebuild_load_test_bucket[0].id`.